Having issues installing Node.js
I follow this: https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager and get the first part of the installation to work in the terminal, and some installation seems to happen, I agree to license terms. Then, when I try the 2nd "fnm env..." I get "fnm : The term 'fnm' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the s
pelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct". I've tried in powershell and vs code too without success and been looking online to find out why it's not working but find nothing. Anyone able to be of assistance?

That error is because you don't have fnm installed (or it isn't in your PATH or environment). Go back to the NodeJS download page and choose "Prebuilt installer". (I'm surprised that isn't the default option).

Perfect, thank you so much!

You just need to restart your Powershell and it will work.
